# Perform action with parameters

Tags: swift, swift4

I have this code

```
if let c: NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString(TestProject.ViewController) as? NSObject.Type{
    let c_tmp = c.init()
    c_tmp.perform(Selector(("test")))
}
```

To execute:

```
@objc public func test(){
    print("This is Test ")
}
```

And it works.

But, at the moment to send a paramter with:

```
if let c: NSObject.Type = NSClassFromString(TestProject.ViewController) as? NSObject.Type{
    let dato:Int=4
    let c_tmp = c.init()
    c_tmp.perform(Selector(("test")), with: dato)
}

@objc public func test(_ dato:Int=0){
        print("This is Test \(dato)")
    }
```

I get the error:

> Unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbec8723cf0 2018-04-17
>   16:59:16.789925-0600 ExcelAgenda[15973:2000202] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[TestProject.ViewController test]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fbec8723cf0'

How I can perform a function with parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong selector. Change

```
c_tmp.perform(Selector(("test")), with: dato)
```

to

```
c_tmp.perform(Selector(("test:")), with: dato)
```

Comment: Or even better, use `#selector(test(_:))` so the compiler can validate it.

Comment: It works, but, for some reason, the value in the method is: `5764607523034232909`

Comment: @MrMins Objective-C must be doing something funny with its translation of the `Int` value. I replaced it with `NSNumber` and it worked as expected.

Comment: You're You're right! you completely right!!! it works with `NSNumber` @JohnMontgomery